# What's the principle behind OpenSSH subsystems (or command= option)?

Tags: openssh, ssh-tunnel, svn-server

In OpenSSH one can declare a subsystem in the configuration file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) or force a command such as `svnserve` to be executed by including this in the `authorized_keys` line for a particular key like this:

```
command="svnserve -t --tunnel-user=alice" ssh-dss AAAA...
command="svnserve -t --tunnel-user=bob" ssh-dss AAAA...
```

thus allowing the same *system* user to be reused for different "identities" within the Subversion (`svnserve`) context.

How would I go about to write a service like `svnserve` myself, allowing to specify the use of the tunnel and how exactly is the data transmitted in these cases? In particular how does the `svnserve` instance "know" by which means to output the data or read input? Does this all happen via `stdout` and `stdin` in such a case and if so, will there be a way to distinguish `stderr` as well?

I imagine the subsystem and the `command=` are using the same mechanism, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

(I left `no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty` out for brevity, but I am aware of them and their use for the scenario.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that `command=` does not invoke a SSH subsystem. It merely runs the command as if it were given on the SSH client's command line; e.g.

```
ssh yourhost "svnserve -t --tunnel-user=alice"

ssh yourhost "git upload-pack /pub/git/myproject.git"

ssh yourhost "ls -la"
```

The above examples should make it clearer that communication with `svnserve` or `git` or `ls` happens over the same stdio (stdin/stdout/stderr) as any other SSH interaction. For SVN and Git, the `ssh` client merely serves as a tool to invoke commands remotely.

---

"Real" subsystems, as configured using the `Subsystem` option in `sshd_config`, aren't that much different. The only major difference is that they can be invoked by a static, well-known name, instead of relying on the remote login shell (bash, zsh, &c) to find the correct executable. For example, the SFTP server can be `/usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server` in one machine, `MULTINET_COMMON_ROOT:[MULTINET]SFTP-SERVER2.EXE` in another, built into `sshd` in third (*Subsystem sftp internal-sftp*), but in all cases clients can still find it using the name `sftp`.

At least in OpenSSH, subsystems can be written just like normal programs that communicate with the client via stdin/stdout/stderr. It seems that passing arbitrary command-line arguments is not allowed, however, so you cannot just configure a single `svnserve` subsystem for all users.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks. I'm aware the subsystems are different, but they're akin to the `command=` method, so I reckoned the communication method is the same.